# как вывести несколько аргументов в cout без <<

Tags: c++

Допустим у меня есть переменная a и b
мне надо их обе вывести,
что можно сделать чтобы не писать стрелочки после переменной a <<

```
std::cout << a << b;
```

так выведется только a

```
std::cout << a,b;
```

так выведется только b

```
std::cout << (a,b)
```

Comment: Потерпите до принятия C++23, будете пользоваться функцией [`print`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/print). Да, жуть страшная — лишние два символа `<<` выводить, как я вас понимаю... :)

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка *как вывести несколько аргументов **в cout** без <<*

Comment: `std::cout.write`.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, но через `printf`...

```
printf(“%d %f”, a, b);
```

---

А так, через `cout` - нельзя, к сожалению:)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ, как ни странно - Никак.
Хотя вообще под ваш запрос подходит такой вариант:

```
std::cout << a;
std::cout << b;
```

Comment: А `printf`? Вроде можно через него...

Comment: @ЧёткаяЧетырка но автор ведь хочет `cout`

Comment: Ну да:) Через `cout` нельзя